# Why is there no error when implementing a class without overriding all its field in Dart?

Tags: dart

```dart
// No error. 
class C extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => null;

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => null;
}
```

Since `C` implements `PreferredSizeWidget` which further implements `Widget`, I must be running into errors if I don't override all the fields from the `Widget` class. But that just doesn't happen. Can anyone please tell me, why?

---

**Edit:**

For analogy, I'm using `W` for `Widget`, `S` for `StatelessWidget` and `P` for `PreferredSizeWidget`, now you can see I'm having the error in my `C` class telling me to override `w1` and `w2` from `W` class.

```dart
abstract class W {
  void w1();
  void w2();
}

abstract class P implements W {
  void p();
}

abstract class S extends W {
  void s();
}

// Error
class C extends S implements P {
  @override
  void p() {}

  @override
  void s() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extending `StatelessWidget` which implements `Widget`, so you get implementations for all the interface members of `Widget`. The `StatelessWidget` further declares two members, where only `build` is a abstract. You provide an implementation of `build`.

The only member added by `PreferredSizeWidget` is `int get preferredSize;`, which you also implement.

So, you have declared or inherited implementations for *all* members of `Widget`, `StatelessWidget` and `PreferredSizeWidget`, which is what the language requires.
You don't need to *override* that implementation unless you want to change it.

Comment: Sir, can you please check the updated question?

Comment: The update is different from the original in that `S` does not have a non-abstract implementation of `W.w1` and `W.w2`. The `StatelessWidget` class has concrete implementations of all the methods of `Widget` (the only one it doesn't inherit from `Widget` is `createElement` which it implements itself).